# NUnit C# using DllImport for an unmanaged dll throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, unmanaged

I'm a newbie to NUnit (in fact to unit testing in general) and I'm trying to write some tests for a little thing I'm working on.

What I'm doing is attempting to write a Wrapper library for libspotify.

An example of what I'm trying to test is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The connection state of the specified session.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sessionPtr">Pointer to Session object</param>
    /// <returns>The connection state - see the ConnectionStateE enum for possible values</returns>
    [DllImport("libspotify")]
    internal static extern ConnectionStateE sp_session_connectionstate(IntPtr sessionPtr);

    /// <summary>
    /// The connection state of the session
    /// </summary>
    public ConnectionStateE GetConnectionState()
    {
        __CheckIsNotDisposed();
        return sp_session_connectionstate(this.Ptr);
    }
```

And then the test itself (in a separate project, same solution)

```
    [Test]
    public void TestSessionInitializeDisconnected()
    {
        using (var sess = new Session())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(sess.ConnectionState, myLibSpotify.Enums.ConnectionStateE.DISCONNECTED);
        }
    }
```

Admittedly this test may not be the most useful but at the moment this is irrelevant. The problem I'm having is when I attempt to run the tests NUnit shows me an exception of:

```
    SpecTests.TestSessionBasics.TestSessionInitializeDisconnected:
    System.BadImageFormatException : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

I'm guessing I've overlooked something here but googleing hasn't really helped because I seem to find results only for testing c++/cli or other results that don't really help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which .net platform do you use x86 or x64?

Comment: Did you manage to run your code e.g. from a console app?

Comment: In the project properties the platform is set to Any CPU - my computer is x64. I'm using VisualStudio 2012 if that helps.

Comment: Yes. the code works from a console app. That was how i was testing originally and now want to use NUnit

Comment: Have just tried it with platform set to x86 and again set to x64. Neither worked although some other tests (not using dllimported methods) failed when I set the platform to x86

Comment: possible duplicate of [nUnit Exception on a 64 bit Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600285/nunit-exception-on-a-64-bit-machine)

Comment: @Hans Passant You are right - the solution was to run nunit-x86 as suggested in an answer in the other question. I assume this means that the dll provided by spotify is x86. I am still wondering though why it works in a potentially x64 console application but not in NUnit.

Comment: @HansPassant While you are right that the answer is the same as found in the other question - and indeed the problem is the same - because this manifests itself in a different way - perhaps closer to the problem itself (where the other question was related to a third party library) I think this may still have some relevance to others who may encounter the same problem - Certainly I wouldn't (and didn't) find the other question when searching for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to run NUnit's 32bit binary instead of the 64bit which is default on a x64 machine.

The reason being the external library I was using was evidently compiled for x86 (32bit) and thus doesn't play nicely with code calling from a 64bit environment.

As @HansPassant mentioned, the solution came from this question: [nUnit Exception on a 64 bit Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600285/nunit-exception-on-a-64-bit-machine)